# Add clicked words to string 2

Tags: javascript

I have the following solution that adds clicked words to a `<input>` field string.

However, I would like to change the javascript to allow me to:

1. Keep text that I manually add to the `<input>` field. At the moment it is overwritten.
2. Exclude full stops from text transferred from `<p>` to `<input>`

**HTML**

```
<p id="target_para">
   Here's an example of the thing you wanted to be made clickable.
</p>
<input type="text" id="display" />
```

**JS**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var para, targets, display, words, clickHandler, updateList, i, j, cur;

    display = document.getElementById("display");
    para = document.getElementById("target_para");

    // Wrap every word in a span element
    para.innerHTML = '<span>' + para.innerText.replace(/ /g,'</span><span> ') + '</span>';

    // Updated target
    targets = para.getElementsByTagName("span");
    words = [];

    // Handler for clicking a clickable element
    clickHandler = function () {
        var text = this.innerText || this.textContent,
            idx = words.indexOf(text);

        if (words.indexOf(text) < 0) {
            // If not already in list, add it
            words.push(text);
        } else {
            // Otherwise remove it
            words.splice(idx, 1);
        }
        updateList();
    };

    // Update display of word list
    updateList = function () {
        while (display.firstChild) {
            display.removeChild(display.firstChild);
        }

        // Set the input box value
        display.value = words.join(",");
    };

    // Bind event handlers to clickable elements
    for (i = 0, j = targets.length; i < j; i++) {
        cur = targets[i];
        cur.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);
    }
}());
```

Comment: *What have you tried?*

Comment: I understand that to keep the text manually entered into the `<input>` field is something that is fundamental, that is based on previous feedback.

Comment: Excluding full stops was something that I tried to achieve using `g/./` but with no success

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var input = document.getElementById('display');
    var paragraph = document.getElementById('target_para');

    paragraph.innerHTML = paragraph.innerHTML.replace(/([^\ ]+)/g, "<span>$1</span>");

    paragraph.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if ('span' !== e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase()) {
            return false;
        }

        input.value += ' ' + e.target.innerHTML;
    }, false);
})();
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HAxCw/

As a word separator for the input I used a space but you can change it to whatever you want. It's this line of code

```
input.value += ' ' + e.target.innerHTML;
```